# JQuery ForEeach Loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working with angularjs ...

I want to implement foreach loop in Jquery

```
vacationSummaries1 =[{VacationType : "X"},{VacationType  : "Y"}]

$.each(($scope.vacationSummaries1, function () 
{
 alert(this.VacationType);
 }));
```

this is not iterating

what is wrong with the Syntax ?

Comment: angular has its own `forEach` : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.forEach

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra set of parentheses, remove them:

```
$.each($scope.vacationSummaries1, function () {
    alert(this.VacationType);
});
```

Also, I'm not sure if `vacationSummaries1`really belongs to `$scope` (I don't know angular).

Comment: I think  you are right. A good IDE or little care could have save from this much headache :). Alternate syntax also helps e.g " `$(vacationSummaries1).each(function(){}); `

Answer (score 1):

Your code for $.each is having an extra set of bracket (...). Avoid using brackets without any specific reason. Here due to your extra brackets .each function is taking complete parameter as single and callback function is not calling. And in angularjs forEach is present to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
angular.forEach($scope.vacationSummaries1,function(v,i){
  alert(v.VacationType)
});
```

OR

```
$.each($scope.vacationSummaries1,function(i,v){
  alert(v.VacationType)
});
```